# Update one mysql column when another is edited

Tags: mysql, trigger

I'm trying to make a datetime field that automatically gets updated with the current time only if there was a change to a certain field.

It seems I have a syntax error.
I try to have `last_progress_date` that gets the date when the `progress_percentage` is updated/edited:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER last_progress_date
ON wp_task_mgr
AFTER UPDATE  
AS BEGIN
   IF UPDATE (progress_percentage)
   SET last_progress_date = GETDATE()
END
```

Answer (score 7):

The code doesn't look like valid Mysql code:

1. `ALTER` is not a valid option
2. No `AS` in Mysql
3. `IF UPDATE(column)`

   - `UPDATE(column)` tests whether column updated in SQLServer, not in Mysql
   - `IF` syntax is invalid (check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)
4. Finally, you can change value of the record which is being modified in `BEFORE` trigger, not in `AFTER`.

You need something like

```
drop trigger if exists last_progress_date;
delimiter // 
CREATE TRIGGER last_progress_date BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_task_mgr 
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
   --assuming progress_percentage is not nullable; if it is, the condition 
   -- needs to be modified to properly handle NULL values
   IF (NEW.progress_percentage != OLD.progress_percentage) 
   THEN
       SET NEW.last_progress_date = GETDATE();
   END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea I was confusing sql and mysql code =S My DB is a mysql one, but I've always used sql with php to get data until now.

I was able to drop the trigger but the last part after delimiter didn't get parsed, so I pasted solely that part, but it has the following error:

 "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 "
→       SET NEW.last_progress_date = GETDATE();

Comment: By the way I added the table names in the first row.
CREATE TRIGGER wp_task_mgr.last_progress_date BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_task_mgr.wp_task_mgr

Comment: I'm not sure if dot can be part of trigger name in mysql. I'd first make it work with simple name.

Comment: How would the trigger know then which table to look at?

Comment: `ON` clause specifies table.  I wanted to meant `wp_task_mgr.last_progress_date ` may be invalid name for mysql trigger (not 100% sure, I haven't worked with mysql for quite a while).   I'd name it , for instance, `BU_wp_task_mgr` ...

Comment: I tried the code "as is" from your answer, but it still have me the same error as above.

Comment: Here is sqlfiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98be3 , sql is working.